Multiple bar charts in grafana
I am quite new to Grafana and I need help in creating a multiple bar chart.
The following is my query
expense_management.expense_data_view where tag in ($tags) group by month_year, tag; 

Ideally, I want one instance of month_year and different verticals grouped together for a month year. However, given that $tags contains - Travel, Food and Rent - this is the output I am getting -

As you can see, there are multiple repeating instances of the year-month. Additionally, I am not able to set different colors to different tags.
I tried it via value mapping and it did not work.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
